# Is there an easy way to select the most recent document per unique value for a particular field?

Tags: mongodb

For example, if you had a dataset that had the fields `_id`, `uuid`, and `timestamp`, and the data contained many thousands of documents, spread across let's say 200 different `uuid`s, and you wanted to return 200 documents, one per `uuid`, with each being the most recent (`timestamp` descending etc), how would you go about this?

I've tried a few solutions and searched through StackOverflow without much luck. I'm sure there is some way to do this with aggregate.

Any tips or nods in the right direction appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out the solution is actually quite simple. Use the distinct field as as the `$group` `_id` and for the value you want, sort it first, and then select the last item with `$last`. Like so:

```
db.example.aggregate([
  { $sort: { "timestamp": 1 } },
  { $group: { _id: "$uuid", timestamp: { $last: "$timestamp" } } }
])
```

And if you want the most recent, I imagine you can just lose the sort with:

```
db.example.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: "$uuid", timestamp: { $last: "$timestamp" } } }
])
```

Well, that settles that.